# Should I tile or carpet first

Tags: flooring

I am getting new carpet in lounge room. I also wanted to tile a small area that leads from lounge room door to outside.  Like a small entry area to stop dirty feet walking straight onto carpet. My question is does it matter if the carpet goes down before we do the tiling?

Answer (score 16):

Tile first, then carpet. Tiling is a messy process. Much easier not to have the carpet there to get messy and/or need to be kept clean while you are tiling.

Comment: That, and it is also easier to butt carpet up to tile than tile to carpet.

Comment: The carpets will also need replacing more often, so by putting then in last, you prove they can be replaced without effecting the tiling.